# Trying to connect my board and winCombos array in javascript for tic-tac-toe

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to connect my winCombos array with my data-indexes on my board so that they reference eachother. I am trying to start the first steps of my check win function but cannot wrap my head around this. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

```
HTML:
<div class="board" id='board'>
        <div class="box unselected" data-index='0'></div>
        <div class="box unselected" data-index='1'></div>
        <div class="box unselected" data-index='2'></div>
        <div class="box unselected" data-index='3'></div>
        <div class="box unselected" data-index='4'></div>
        <div class="box unselected" data-index='5'></div>
        <div class="box unselected" data-index='6'></div>
        <div class="box unselected" data-index='7'></div>
        <div class="box unselected" data-index='8'></div>
    </div>
```

Javascript:

```
    const winCombos = [
        [0, 1, 2],
        [3, 4, 5],
        [6, 7, 8],
        [0, 3, 6],
        [1, 4, 7],
        [2, 5, 8],
        [0, 4, 8],
        [2, 4, 6]
    ]


function which(event) {
    console.log(`Index ${event.target.dataset.index} got clicked!`);


    if (count % 2 == 1 && event.target.classList.contains('unselected')) {
        count++
        event.target.innerHTML = '<i class="fas fa-times"></i>';
        turn.innerHTML = "O Player's Turn";
        event.target.classList.remove('unselected');
        event.target.classList.remove('selectedX');
        event.target.classList.add('selectedO');
    }
    if (count % 2 == 0 && event.target.classList.contains('unselected')) {
        count++
        event.target.innerHTML = '<i class="far fa-circle"></i>';
        turn.innerHTML = "X Player's Turn";
        event.target.classList.remove('unselected');
        event.target.classList.remove('selectedO');
        event.target.classList.add('selectedX');
    }



}

function checkWin() {
    if (winCombos[0].classList.contains(selectedX)) {
        console.log('win')
    }
}
checkWin();
```

Comment: Please add some more code or add a fiddle.

Comment: updated my javascript

Comment: Just walk through your winning array. If the pieces found at the indexes in any of the sub-arrays belong to the same player, they win. Get all of the game squares divs into an array with `let squares = document.querySelectorAll(`div.board > div.box')` and they'll be easy to check against the indices in the sub-arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's something for you to play with.

Basically, if the squares found at all 3 positions in one of the sub-arrays are both the same and belong to a player, that player wins.

What I do is grab the text from the first square mentioned in one of the items in the winCombos array. I then check to make sure it holds something, exiting if not. I then check that both the 2nd and 3rd elements match the first.

Hope you find it useful.

```js
"use strict";
window.addEventListener('load', onLoaded, false);
function onLoaded(evt)
{
    document.querySelector('div').addEventListener('click', onBoardClicked, false);
}

const winCombos = [
        [0, 1, 2],
        [3, 4, 5],
        [6, 7, 8],
        [0, 3, 6],
        [1, 4, 7],
        [2, 5, 8],
        [0, 4, 8],
        [2, 4, 6]
    ];
    
function onBoardClicked(evt)
{
    let elem = evt.target;
    
    if (elem.classList.contains('box') == false)
        return;
        
    if (elem.classList.contains('unselected'))
    {
        elem.classList.remove('unselected');
        elem.classList.add('selected')
        elem.textContent = 'X';
        checkWin();
    }
}

function checkWin()
{
    let squares = document.querySelectorAll('div.box');
    
    for (var comboIndex=0,n=winCombos.length; comboIndex<n; comboIndex++)
    {
        let curCombo = winCombos[comboIndex];
        let value = squares[curCombo[0]].textContent;
        if (value !== '')
        {
            if (squares[curCombo[1]].textContent == value && squares[curCombo[2]].textContent == value)
            {
                alert(`Winner, winner - player ${value}`);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```css
.box
{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 48px;
    height: 48px;
    background: #bbb;
    line-height: 16px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.board
{
    width: 160px;
    height: 160px;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="board" id='board'>
        <div class="box unselected" data-index='0'></div>
        <div class="box unselected" data-index='1'></div>
        <div class="box unselected" data-index='2'></div>
        <div class="box unselected" data-index='3'></div>
        <div class="box unselected" data-index='4'></div>
        <div class="box unselected" data-index='5'></div>
        <div class="box unselected" data-index='6'></div>
        <div class="box unselected" data-index='7'></div>
        <div class="box unselected" data-index='8'></div>
    </div>
```